# Mel separated filter banks

Tags: filters, frequency, speech-processing, speech-recognition, bandpass

I am currently a bit confused. 
I am currently trying to understand the MFCC extraction process, and don't understand how the Mel filter banks only provide a scalar output from each filter bank. What does this scalar value mean? I know the filters aren't infinitely narrow, thereby only allowing one frequency so what about the frequencies around the center frequency?

Comment: The scalar output of each filterbank is given by the total energy of the frequencies that the filter let's through. You will have one scalar value for each filter. After performing the DCT on the obtained sequence of scalar values you get the MFCC

Comment: I learned lot from [here](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/) and [here](https://haythamfayek.com/2016/04/21/speech-processing-for-machine-learning.html). Do not forget to read comment in the first link in bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalar Value from the output of each mel filter bank is accumulated scaled magnitudes of frequencies present in mel filters range/bandwidth.